# How to delete the rows from a table where a column contains a specific String?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

As my title question, I want to delete some rows of table on SQLite where contains specific string.
Here are my methods I tried but there are no any row is deleted. I checked table of SQLite database by get it out and put in to DB Browser for SQLite which is downloaded from https://sqlitebrowser.org/

```
  public void delete1(String table,String COLUMN,String link) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+table+" WHERE "+COLUMN+" LIKE "+link+"%");
   }

 public void delete2(String table,String name){ 
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
   db.delete(table, "PRODUCTNAME" + "LIKE ?", new String[]{name+"%"}) ;
  }
```

Could you tell me how to do it or how have i to correct code ?

Comment: Your 2nd attempt misses a space, change to: `"PRODUCTNAME LIKE ?"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `db.delete(table, "PRODUCTNAME " + "LIKE ?", new String[]{name+"%"}) ;` will only delete rows that start with the value in name.

Perhpas you want :-

```
db.delete(table, "PRODUCTNAME " + "LIKE ?", new String[]{"%"+name+"%"}) ;
```

Then it would delete rows that contain the value rather than start with the value.

With `db.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+table+" WHERE "+COLUMN+" LIKE "+link+"%");` you need to enclose the string in single quotes and assuming that you want to delete a row that contains the value then use :-

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+table+" WHERE "+COLUMN+" LIKE '%"+link+"%'");
```

- Using the **delete** convenience method (the first part) is the better option as it protects against SQL Injection, it properly encloses the value, builds the underlying SQL and also returns the number of affected (deleted) rows.

If you use the following, this will write dome debugging information  that may assist in debugging :-

```
public void delete2(String table,String name){ 
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
   Log.d("DELETEINFO","Attempting to delete rows with \n\t->" + name); 
   int deletedCount = db.delete(table, "PRODUCTNAME " + "LIKE ?", new String[]{"%"+name+"%"}) >0) ;
   Log.d("DELETEINFO","Deleted " + deletedCount + " rows.");
}
```

Comment: I tried  db.delete(table, "PRODUCTNAME" + "LIKE ?", new String[]{"%"+name+"%"}) ; It doesn't work :(

Comment: @ELIP then it either crashes, if so edit your question with the stack-trace, or it deletes nothing (check the result and the value being passed) or the method that you are determining that nothing has been deleted is at fault. See amended answer for code that could determine which of the 3.

Comment: I get into database and see inside the table by this tool https://sqlitebrowser.org. I double check there are no any row deleted

Comment: before perfoming the query here you can check your query in Db browser,it will help you to perform perfect query

Comment: @ELIP db.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+table+" WHERE "+COLUMN+" LIKE '"+link+" %'"); try this

Comment: I really appreciate you @MikeT, forpas, rachna to take the time to help me However . There are still nothing to change on my table of SQLite. It's strange with this https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-delete/

Comment: @ELIP ignore sqlitebrowser add logging as suggested and scrutinise the actual data. Perhaps add the following code before and after the deletion  `Cursor csr = db.query(table,null,null,null,null,null,null,null); DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(db,csr);` (note after will just be 'csr = db.query(.............') This will extract all rows and dump the Cursor to the log. The are a number of issues where the database view in Sqlitebrowser. may not be the actual database.

Comment: @MikeT, forpas, rachna I got my error I missed a space from my query  "PRODUCTNAMELIKE ?" in my method  as forpas said above.  I was ashamed to ask you. I'm so sorry to bother you. I hope you can up votes my question Because this question made my stackoverflow's account is blocked. I can't ask any new question as https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans. Thank you so much